# iPhone Application with a password

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I want to start my iPhone application with a password.
How I do that ?

Regards
Akram Hamed

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create an `UIAlertView` instance and add a `UITextField` as a subview. This is where the user will put in the password. When the alert view completes, get the password and see if it's the right one. Then continue running the app or quit.

Comment: The officially supported way would be to do it with (for example) a modal view controller with a `UITextField`, rather than messing with the subviews of a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: What's wrong with using a UIAlertView? The App Store app uses it for receiving a password, for example. I'm just curious, as I've seen this comment before (also, I use it in one of my apps)

Comment: To add to this answer... Make sure to store a hashed version of the password. Use md5 or sha1. Check that hashed value rather than the actual password. Also, you might want to restrict it only to Latin letters.

Comment: @donkim: "What's wrong with using a UIAlertView?" I don't believe the application has access to the underlying text field. The application *will* be able to retrieve the text (ie, password), but will not be able to zeroize or scrub the underlying data from the text field. You should use a custom view which implements UIKeyInput protocol for zeroization.

Answer (score -1):

It's pretty easy, just ask your user for a password when your app starts.